Any rigorous construction of $\phi^4$ theories without the mass term in the Lagrangian? (revised)
There are various papers on rigorous construction of massive $\phi^4$ theories in $2$ or $3$ Euclidean dimensions.
In 2D, there are in fact more general results such as this one by Glimm, Jaffe and Spencer and this one by Glimm and Dimock.
I wonder if a rigorous construction of massless theories is also possible.
More specifically, I remember that no wave function or coupling constant renormalization is needed for super-renormalizable Bosonic theories in $2$ Euclidean dimensions. Therefore, interacting scalar fields in a super-renormalizable theory may still be defined as operator-valued distributions on the Fock space. Moreover, their UV asymptotics is known to be identical to free fields, so that their co-located products may be defined in the same way as Wick products of free fields. The two cited papers above consider the Hamiltonian of the following form:
$$
H(\lambda,m_0,h) = H_{\text{free}}(m_0)+ \lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} :P(\Phi):(x)h(x)dx
$$
where $h$ is any compactly supported function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $0 \leq h \leq 1$, and $H_{\text{free}}(m_0)$ is the Hamiltonian operator for the free Euclidean scalar given by
$$
H_{\text{free}}(m_0)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \Bigl\{ :\bigl(\nabla \phi\bigr)^2:(x)+m_0^2 :\phi^2(x) \Bigr\}dx
$$
Here, $\phi$ is the free Euclidean scalar field of (bare) mass $m_0$. Also, $\lambda$ is a coupling constant and $P$ is a polynomial such that $\lambda P$ is bounded from below and self-interaction described by $P$ is super-renormalizable. Lastly, $\Phi$ is the "interacting" scalar field for the self-interacting scalar theory described by $P$. In fact, the two papers above establish the limit under which $h \to 1$ under the assumption that $\lambda/m_0^2$ is sufficiently small.
With these notations, my question may be asking if there is any rigorous construction of a theory with $m_0=0$. The main issues I have are:

How do we handle the IR singularity for both the free field $\phi$ and (if existent) $\Phi$?

Again, if such a theory exist, does it have the mass gap in the sense that cluster decomposition of the Schwinger functions is exponential?


I deeply appreciate any comment or suggestion of references.

Shouldn't renormalization create a mass term anyway? "That which is not forbidden is mandatory" and there is no symmetry that a massless $\phi^4$ theory has that a massive doesn't have.

@gmvh Could you explain more in detail what you mean by "renormalization creates a mass term"? I guess this corresponds to the exponential clustering in my post. Also, I agree with you about symmetry.

This is very easy to see with Dyson-Schwinger equations for the correlation functions because one gets the two-point function $G_2(x,x)$, a constant to be renormalized, providing a mass term to all the set of equations.

@Jon Hmm...I still do not get the whole picture. Yes, you need UV renormalization for the co-located two-point function. However, I do not see what you mean by a "providing a mass term" in the equation of motion. To me, it seems like a physical argument, which may be rigorously justified. Could you provide more details if possible?

@Isaac It is not easy to make this rigorous, but the equation for the one-point correlation function is $\partial^2G_1(x)+3\lambda(G_2(x,x)G_1(x)+[G_1(x)]^3+G_3(x,x,x))=0$. The "mass term" $3\lambda G_2(x,x)$ is present in all the hierarchy of equations for the higher order correlation functions.

@Isaac It may help if you take the effort to formulate your question as a well-posed mathematical question, even if it is only an instance of the "meta question" you're really interested in.

@MartinHairer I hope this revision clarifies my question.

@Isaac Sort of. What you really mean is that one takes the limit $h\to 1$ of the measures $Z^{-1}\mu_f \exp(-H_i)$ where $\mu_f$ is the Gaussian measure with covariance $(m_0^2 -\Delta)^{-1}$ and $H_i$ is the ($h$-dependent) "interacting part" of the Hamiltonian $H$. Now the problem for starters is that there is no Gaussian field with covariance $(-\Delta)^{-1}$: it is only defined modulo constants...

@MartinHairer I vaguely remember the fact. So..can we construct something in some sort of quotient space modulo constant? The other (more heuristic) comments seem to imply that there is some theory with mass generation?

@MartinHairer If it is too cumbersome to answer here, could you recommend me any relevant references? I deeply appreciate any suggestions from you.

@Isaac The follow-up papers by Glimm-Jaffe-Spencer (in particular their 1975 paper) show that if in your notations you take say $m_0 = \lambda = 1$ and $P(\Phi) = \Phi^4 - \kappa \Phi^2$, then there is a phase transition at some value of $\kappa$ (not necessarily $1$). The theory at the phase transition is the massless theory you're after.

@MartinHairer It is surprising that you can get a massless theory even if you start with nonzero bare mass. I will take a close look. Thank you.

@Isaac The "bare mass" doesn't even have a canonical meaning here. You just get a one-parameter family of limits (modulo non-uniqueness at $\kappa$ above the transition) without any canonical parametrisation a priori. A posteriori there's one value of the parameter at which correlations decay algebraically, and that's then a natural "origin"...

@Isaac Actually, surprisingly enough, that's not surprising at all. The zero-mass case is not special (no increased symmetries) for scalar fields, so mass renormalizes additively (in the sense that the correlation length is not proportional to the inverse of the bare mass) and the critical value of the bare mass is generically non-zero.

@gmvh I now understand and agree with that. Perhaps, my concern about IR singularity of massless free scalars (as pointed out by Prof. Hairer) somewhat obscured into the renormalization issue..

@MartinHairer Thank you for your clarification!
